# Href not working when class is mention in a img tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

My html code is

```
 <a href="./abc/main.html"><img src="./img/abc.png" class="abc"  />
 <a href="./color/main.pnhtml"><img src="./img/abc.png" class="color"  />
```

where in class=" abc" & class="color" I have defined the css code for position of my image abc and color respectively. However when I hovre my mouse over the abc image or color image and click it always open color/main.html page even when i click the abc image it open color/main.html page
Please Help..!!

Comment: That's because you didn't close the anchors, they aren't self-closing

Answer (score 0):

You don't close your "a" tag.

```
<a href="./abc/main.html">
    <img src="./img/abc.png" class="abc"  />
</a>
<a href="./color/main.html">
    <img src="./img/abc.png" class="color"  />
</a>
```

Further information about the "a" tag:

Link to W3 Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: Still When I m Closing Its not Working Please Help..!!